# Is there a way to re-map a key on an Android keyboard to trigger the microphone?

Tags: java, android

For example, if I wanted to re-map any button, such as the "U" button on an Android keyboard into triggering the microphone (such as the speech-to-text function), is there a way to do it? I'm thinking of something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_U) {
         // trigger microphone
      }
}
```

Is there a way to trigger the microphone in this case?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "trigger the microphone"? Are you talking while the user is running your app? Or as a system-wide shortcut?

Comment: Hi @JoachimSauer, basically a system-wide shortcut on my own device, no app involved. For example, whenever I press the "U" button on the keyboard, the speech-to-text function should pop-up